# iOS: Getting directions for the current destination set in Maps

Tags: ios, iphone, mapkit

Is there any way to request the list of directions for the active destination in iOS (Maps or Google Maps). I see a reference to "Routing App" but I cannot find any documentation on it.

Basically, I would like to retrieve a the next navigation step so I can forward that to my Bluetooth device and show it to the end user, similar to how FitBit and WatchOS do it.

Answer (score 0):

Many ways to do this.

Since you asked for MapKit, have a look at

`MKDirections` https://developer.apple.com/documentation/mapkit/mkdirections

In the result you should find steps: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/mapkit/mkroute/step

These steps should be what you're looking for.

Comment: SO, the main problem I have is that I want to get the current directions as input by the user in the iOS Maps app; I don't want to force them to input a destination in my own app. There doesn't seem to be a way to pull the current destination from Maps; not that I can see at least.